# How to get specific fields with Facebook API/SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm playing around a bit with Facebook API + PHP SDK but I'm stuck..

I'm trying to fetch all my wall posts and (if attached) the images.
Fetching all my posts goes fine but it doesn't automatically include the image. So my main question is 'How can I add fields to the fetch command'

Here is the code I'm using now:

```php
/* handle the result */
try {
    $response = $fb->get('/me/posts', $token);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}


// Page 1
$feedEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
```

According to the facebook documents I should use this:

```php
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me/posts',
  array(
    'fields' => 'full_picture,message'
  )
);

$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

But the execute and getGraphobject method don't even exist in my SDK files (which is the latest version)

Answer (score 0):

To get specific fields, you can try changing

```
$response = $fb->get('/me/posts', $token);
```

to

```
$response = $fb->get('/me/posts?fields=full_picture,message', $token);
```